# Populate array of structure using define

Tags: c

I have to create array of structure using a define. Please suggest me how to do it.

```
file1.c have data
{
    "string1",
     13         
}

file2.c have data              
{
    "string2",
    14         
}
```

Need to pass this data to one common define so that it can populate data like below:

```
struct test data[]=
{
    {"string1", 13}, 
    {"string2", 14}
}
```

Let me elaborate it here like this:

```
file1.c
ADD_DATA_IN_STRUCT(....) ---> pass data {"string1", 13}

file2.c
ADD_DATA_IN_STRUCT(....) ---> pass data {"string1", 14}

main.h
#define ADD_DATA_IN_STRUCT(....)  ---> should expand to
struct test data[]=
{
    {"string1", 13}, 
    {"string2", 14}
}
```

Comment: You have data sitting in other `c` files?

Comment: It isn't obvious if the struct should contain a hard copy of the string or just a pointer to it. Please clarify. And what do you mean with "a define", "a common define"? Do you mean declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps, I've left out the details.

```
// 1. define the test struct
define struct test {
    char *string;
    int number;
};

// 2. define the data array
struct test data[2];

// 3. read file, assign value to corresponding fields in data array
// you may want to dynamically allocated memory for `string` using `malloc`
// or if the string has a maximum size, define it using `char string[MAX_SIZE]` instead
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed giving details that I want this initialized structure during pre-compilation time itself. Hence looking for common  #define which can take data from other files and build initialized structure and which will be present during precompilation time.

Comment: You mean having the files copied to C source file before it goes into the compiler? In this case, as C is not a dynamically programming language, you will need to use some other language (like `Python`) or program (like `shell` script), to complete the above steps treating the data files and C source file as text files.

Comment: @ManishB Why not simply read the files and insert them yourself? This is the most straightforward way.